# PECL install no releases available

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, docker, pecl

```
RUN pecl install mongodb-1.4.2
```

Resulted in this output:

```
RUN pecl install mongodb-1.4.2 &&   docker-php-ext-enable mongodb:
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"
install failed
```

Could this be a cert issue? because if I try to wget i get following:

```
Connecting to pecl.php.net (104.236.228.160:443)
ssl_client: pecl.php.net: certificate verification failed: certificate has expired
```

PHP Version
php:7.0

Is there a way to fix this or do I need to just wait for them to update the cert?

Comment: The certificat is valid, it's a let's encrypt. May be your server doesn't have the CA for verification

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're explicitly doing `wget` when `pecl install` downloads the package for you. Also, your versions are pretty ancient. What docker image are you starting with?

Comment: @AlexHowansky php:7.0-fpm-alpine, i ran pecl install, it didnt work, then tried wget.

edit: there was a mistake in the question, that should clear your confusion :D

Comment: Within the last year or two the original LetsEncrypt CA certificate expired and was replaced by a new certificate. You need to run updates on the machine that's running this command to get the updated CA certificate package for your distro. This will likely solve a fair number of issues on the system, not just PECL access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your base image is too old and doesn't have the appropriate certificate information, and `apk update && apk upgrade` don't get you there. I don't see any way to tell pecl to ignore certs but you could do:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://pecl.php.net/get/mongodb-1.4.2.tgz
pecl install --offline ./mongodb-1.4.2.tgz
```

Of course, I'd have recommend not using such old versions and then it won't be a problem.

Comment: It was working until today. Why would it become too old just like that.

Comment: It's possible they installed a new cert server-side.

Comment: This was the solution for me, please take into consideration the version, in my case 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by removing the offending certificate from the docker image. I'm also on a situation where I cannot upgrade the PHP version and I need timezonedb always up-to-date from PECL.
After removing them PECL works normally.

Read  https://github.com/libressl/portable/issues/692#issuecomment-937800309 lead to  https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/3c95f6f12797ebbdedb8d5f712eb65bd04fe233a

I then made a grep to see where the cert was on my docker image (php5.6-alpine) and removed it.
Two files required a patch, and two files were the whole certificate.

```
#12 [web base 4/7] RUN grep -r Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ /etc
#12 0.445 /etc/ssl/cert.pem:Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
#12 0.754 /etc/ssl/certs/2e5ac55d.0:Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
#12 0.754 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert-DST_Root_CA_X3.pem:Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
#12 0.754 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
```

Patch `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

```
--- /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.ori
+++ /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
@@ -956,27 +956,6 @@
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-MIIDSjCCAjKgAwIBAgIQRK+wgNajJ7qJMDmGLvhAazANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA/
-MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
-DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTAwMDkzMDIxMTIxOVoXDTIxMDkzMDE0MDExNVow
-PzEkMCIGA1UEChMbRGlnaXRhbCBTaWduYXR1cmUgVHJ1c3QgQ28uMRcwFQYDVQQD
-Ew5EU1QgUm9vdCBDQSBYMzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB
-AN+v6ZdQCINXtMxiZfaQguzH0yxrMMpb7NnDfcdAwRgUi+DoM3ZJKuM/IUmTrE4O
-rz5Iy2Xu/NMhD2XSKtkyj4zl93ewEnu1lcCJo6m67XMuegwGMoOifooUMM0RoOEq
-OLl5CjH9UL2AZd+3UWODyOKIYepLYYHsUmu5ouJLGiifSKOeDNoJjj4XLh7dIN9b
-xiqKqy69cK3FCxolkHRyxXtqqzTWMIn/5WgTe1QLyNau7Fqckh49ZLOMxt+/yUFw
-7BZy1SbsOFU5Q9D8/RhcQPGX69Wam40dutolucbY38EVAjqr2m7xPi71XAicPNaD
-aeQQmxkqtilX4+U9m5/wAl0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNV
-HQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMSnsaR7LHH62+FLkHX/xBVghYkQMA0GCSqG
-SIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCjGiybFwBcqR7uKGY3Or+Dxz9LwwmglSBd49lZRNI+DT69
-ikugdB/OEIKcdBodfpga3csTS7MgROSR6cz8faXbauX+5v3gTt23ADq1cEmv8uXr
-AvHRAosZy5Q6XkjEGB5YGV8eAlrwDPGxrancWYaLbumR9YbK+rlmM6pZW87ipxZz
-R8srzJmwN0jP41ZL9c8PDHIyh8bwRLtTcm1D9SZImlJnt1ir/md2cXjbDaJWFBM5
-JDGFoqgCWjBH4d1QB7wCCZAA62RjYJsWvIjJEubSfZGL+T0yjWW06XyxV3bqxbYo
-Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
------END CERTIFICATE-----
-
------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 MIIDtzCCAp+gAwIBAgIQDOfg5RfYRv6P5WD8G/AwOTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBl
 MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
 d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSQwIgYDVQQDExtEaWdpQ2VydCBBc3N1cmVkIElEIFJv
```

Patch `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`

```
--- cert.pem.ori
+++ cert.pem
@@ -2182,49 +2182,6 @@
 gKDWHrO8Dw9TdSmq6hN35N6MgSGtBxBHEa2HPQfRdbzP82Z+
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 
-### Digital Signature Trust Co.
-
-=== /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
-Certificate:
-    Data:
-        Version: 3 (0x2)
-        Serial Number:
-            44:af:b0:80:d6:a3:27:ba:89:30:39:86:2e:f8:40:6b
-    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
-        Validity
-            Not Before: Sep 30 21:12:19 2000 GMT
-            Not After : Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
-        Subject: O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3
-        X509v3 extensions:
-            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
-                CA:TRUE
-            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
-                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
-            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
-                C4:A7:B1:A4:7B:2C:71:FA:DB:E1:4B:90:75:FF:C4:15:60:85:89:10
-SHA1 Fingerprint=DA:C9:02:4F:54:D8:F6:DF:94:93:5F:B1:73:26:38:CA:6A:D7:7C:13
-SHA256 Fingerprint=06:87:26:03:31:A7:24:03:D9:09:F1:05:E6:9B:CF:0D:32:E1:BD:24:93:FF:C6:D9:20:6D:11:BC:D6:77:07:39
------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-MIIDSjCCAjKgAwIBAgIQRK+wgNajJ7qJMDmGLvhAazANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA/
-MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
-DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTAwMDkzMDIxMTIxOVoXDTIxMDkzMDE0MDExNVow
-PzEkMCIGA1UEChMbRGlnaXRhbCBTaWduYXR1cmUgVHJ1c3QgQ28uMRcwFQYDVQQD
-Ew5EU1QgUm9vdCBDQSBYMzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB
-AN+v6ZdQCINXtMxiZfaQguzH0yxrMMpb7NnDfcdAwRgUi+DoM3ZJKuM/IUmTrE4O
-rz5Iy2Xu/NMhD2XSKtkyj4zl93ewEnu1lcCJo6m67XMuegwGMoOifooUMM0RoOEq
-OLl5CjH9UL2AZd+3UWODyOKIYepLYYHsUmu5ouJLGiifSKOeDNoJjj4XLh7dIN9b
-xiqKqy69cK3FCxolkHRyxXtqqzTWMIn/5WgTe1QLyNau7Fqckh49ZLOMxt+/yUFw
-7BZy1SbsOFU5Q9D8/RhcQPGX69Wam40dutolucbY38EVAjqr2m7xPi71XAicPNaD
-aeQQmxkqtilX4+U9m5/wAl0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNV
-HQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMSnsaR7LHH62+FLkHX/xBVghYkQMA0GCSqG
-SIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCjGiybFwBcqR7uKGY3Or+Dxz9LwwmglSBd49lZRNI+DT69
-ikugdB/OEIKcdBodfpga3csTS7MgROSR6cz8faXbauX+5v3gTt23ADq1cEmv8uXr
-AvHRAosZy5Q6XkjEGB5YGV8eAlrwDPGxrancWYaLbumR9YbK+rlmM6pZW87ipxZz
-R8srzJmwN0jP41ZL9c8PDHIyh8bwRLtTcm1D9SZImlJnt1ir/md2cXjbDaJWFBM5
-JDGFoqgCWjBH4d1QB7wCCZAA62RjYJsWvIjJEubSfZGL+T0yjWW06XyxV3bqxbYo
-Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
------END CERTIFICATE-----
-
 ### Disig a.s.
 
 === /C=SK/L=Bratislava/O=Disig a.s./CN=CA Disig Root R2
```

Then remove the other two files which are the whole cert `/etc/ssl/certs/2e5ac55d.0`  and `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert-DST_Root_CA_X3.pem`

These are the final dockerfile lines, I left the grep line intentionally to debug this if some file is renamed

```
COPY docker/ca-certificates.patch /tmp
COPY docker/cert.pem.patch /tmp
RUN grep -r Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ /etc
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN patch /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /tmp/ca-certificates.patch && \
    patch /etc/ssl/cert.pem /tmp/cert.pem.patch && \
    rm /etc/ssl/certs/2e5ac55d.0 && \
    rm /etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert-DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
```

PS: Originally from https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/11486#issuecomment-1626075999 answering here too just in case.

Comment: This is the answer. It's a little easier on the official Docker PHP 5.6 image (Debian stretch), just add `RUN rm /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt` to the Dockerfile.

Comment: In my case for image _php:7.0.33-fpm-alpine_ i had to run commands:
`rm /etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert-DST_Root_CA_X3.pem &&
cat /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem > /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt &&
cat /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem > /etc/ssl/cert.pem`

Comment: @PST Thanks a lot. What a time-saver! JSON Machine builds will run again 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today (with `apcu` package, but package doesn't matter, when something like this happens). I've decided not to rely on the intermittent `pecl` working. My solution is based on @alex-howansky answer:

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y \
&& apt-get install -y ca-certificates \
&& update-ca-certificates \
&& apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    ...
    wget \
&& apt-get autoremove -y \
&& docker-php-ext-install \
    intl \
    ...
### SOLUTION IS BELOW. ###
&& pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
&& { \
    pecl install apcu || ( \
        wget --no-check-certificate https://pecl.php.net/get/APCu -O ./apcu_latest.tgz \
        && pecl install --offline ./apcu_latest.tgz \
        && rm ./apcu_latest.tgz \
    ); \
} \
...
```

If `pecl install apcu` is successful, this command is used. This is preferred command, because dealing with expired certificates by bypassing SSL checks is not recommended for production environments, as it poses security risks.

But we cannot allow certificate outages to disrupt the application. So, if `pecl install apcu` failed, commands after `||` are used (download package - latest version in my case, install it and remove downloaded `./apcu_latest.tgz`).

PS. You can see link to latest package version (if you need latest) on https://pecl.php.net/. Just find you package and look for "[ Latest Tarball ]" on the package page:

[image]

PPS. [Here](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/11486#issuecomment-1713735572) is the report about today's problem (certificate has been expired for the umpteenth time).